# Combine multiple rows with the same ID field into one row, by adding the neccessary columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rows

Below is what I am working with that is already stored in a table

```
ParentID   ComputerName ProductCode
--------   ------------    ------------
117   AZ18LTDJBN2R1 EEADMIN_1000
117   AZ18LTDJBN2R1 EEGO____1000
117   AZ18LTDJBN2R1 EEPC
117   AZ18LTDJBN2R1 EPOAGENT3000
117   AZ18LTDJBN2R1 HOSTIPS_8000
117   AZ18LTDJBN2R1 PCR_____1000
117   AZ18LTDJBN2R1 SITEADV_3500
117   AZ18LTDJBN2R1 SUPPCLNT1000
117   AZ18LTDJBN2R1 VIRUSCAN8800
```

How can I merge this 9 rows into 1 row with added columns for each record/productcode?

```
ParentID   ComputerName EEADMIN        EEGO            EEPC    EPOAgent        etc.   
--------   ------------    ------------  -------------   ------   ----------     ------
 117      AZ18LTDJBN2R1 EEADMIN_1000  EEGO____1000    EEPC     EPOAGENT3000    etc.
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And where do you store values, which you want for field names of target table? `EEADMIN`,`EEGO`,`EEPC`,`EPOAgent`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select ParentId, ComputerName,
       max(case when ProductCode like 'EEADMIN%' then ProductCode end) as EEAdmin,
       max(case when ProductCode like 'EEGO%' then ProductCode end) as EEGO,
       max(case when ProductCode like 'EEPC%' then ProductCode end) as EEPC,
       . . .
from t
group by ParentId, ComputerName
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. I actually used your idea in a nested query and then got the correct data by selecting from that. Thanks agaun for the help. It's working sweet now.